# Why "keep_window_open()" doesn't wait for a character to be entered?

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm new to programming, and I'm trying to learn C++ by myself, and I'm following "Programming principles and practice using C++".

I was trying to do an exercise that, after various other steps, asked me to

> " ...change the body of the loop so that it reads just one double each time around. Define two variables to keep track of which is the smallest and which is the largest value you have seen so far. Each time through the loop write out the
>   value entered. If it’s the smallest so far, write the smallest so far after the number. If it is the largest so far, write the largest so far after the number".

I wrote the following code so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { cout<<"\nType a character to exit: "; char ch; cin>>ch; }

int main()
{
double val1 = 0, smallest = 0, largest = 0;
int flag = 0;
while (cin >>val1) {
    if (val1=='|')
        break;
    else
        cout <<val1 <<'\n';
    if (flag==0) {
        smallest = val1;
        cout <<smallest <<" it's the smallest value so far.\n";
    }
    if (val1<smallest) {
        smallest = val1;
        cout <<smallest <<" it's the smallest value so far.\n"; }
    else if (val1>largest) {
             largest = val1;
             cout <<largest <<" it's the largest value so far.\n"; }
    ++flag;
}

keep_window_open();

return 0;
}
```

My problem is that when I input a character, e.g. 'c', the program ends, although the program should end, hypothetically, only when I enter '|', and I get:

```
c

Type a character to exit:
Process returned 0 (0x0)     execution time : ...
Press any key to continue.
```

and `"keep_window_open()"` doesn't wait for a character to be entered. I just can't understand what happens, and why. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the problem is in the way you defined your loop expression.
Neither cin nor its operator ">>" return a true / false value that you can work with. They return an iStream object which could be a dubious translation to true or false via an automated casting that happens behind the curtains. They will however return null when the input cannot be set inside your variable like in the case of trying to put 'c' into a double, and null translates into false.

What I suggest for you is to create a simple while(true) loop and when you get the "|" character from the user(as a string) you break the loop. until then the loop continues. then inside the loop parse your value and work on it according to your logic(minimum / maximum)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

`while (cin >>val1)` reads input into a double. If you input something that cannot be read as a double like "|" then this will fail and cause your loop to exit.

You then try to read more input while `cin` is in an error state.

**Solution**

Call `cin.clear()` to first clear any error flags and then `cin.ignore(1000, '\n')` to throw away anything left hanging in the input stream.

```
inline void keep_window_open() 
{ 
    cout << "\nType a character to exit: "; 
    char ch; 

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    cin >> ch; 
}
```

**Note**

```
if (val1=='|')
    break;
```

This code will never be true because if you try to input the pipe character your while loop will fall through before ever getting to it.